# LTRIM give strange answers in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have used the following query

```
  select ltrim('|7732-18-5|1314-13-2|','7732-18-5|') from dual;
```

expected answer is 1314-13-2| but gives the following answer 4-13-2|.

Is it a Bug in Oracle? or  I am a stupid programmer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2018.htm#OLADM594 :

> The LTRIM function removes characters from the left of a text expression, with all the leftmost characters that appear in another text expression removed. The function begins scanning the base text expression from its first character and removes all characters that appear in the trim expression until reaching a character that is not in the trim expression and then returns the result.

In this case, the number "4" is not in your trim expressen `'7732-18-5|'`, so everything up until the 4 is removed, returning only 4-13-2|

To get the expected output, consider using the REPLACE function instead:

```
select replace('|7732-18-5|1314-13-2|','7732-18-5|') from dual;
```